# Conflicting D3 and JQuery click events on a JQuery-based select menu

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm using Wallace Erick's codepen for a JQuery based select menu and it seems to be conflicting with D3 click events.

https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz

The D3 line of code I'm using is the following:

```
d3.select("select").on("change", function(){...});
```

Edit: I have a codepen included which shows D3 functionality working with the JQuery code commented out. When you select an animal from the dropdown, the sentence below it updates. When you uncomment out the JQuery code, the select menu is now properly styled, but the sentence no longer updates.

https://codepen.io/rmmasri/pen/xqvmKd

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code where you've used this custom select menu? Check the [guide on creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: Codepen added! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript you're using from the first codepen is disabling the original `select`, and replacing it with a `div` and an `ul` which are together operating some `select`-like behaviour.

Opening an Element Inspector confirms this, showing the DOM to look like the following:

```
<div class="select">
    <select class="select-hidden" id="animal">
        <option disabled="" selected="" value="hide">Animal</option>
        <option value="all animals">[All]</option>
        <option value="chickens">Chickens</option>
        <option value="wolves">Wolves</option>
    </select>
    <div class="select-styled">Chickens</div>
    <ul class="select-options" style="display: none;">
        <li rel="hide">Animal</li>
        <li rel="all animals">[All]</li>
        <li rel="chickens">Chickens</li>
        <li rel="wolves">Wolves</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Your `d3.select('select')` is catching the `select` correctly, but the `change` event is never fired, as the `select` is never changed. Instead, you could connect the `change` event to the `div#select-styled` element, or you could update the JavaScript from Wallace Erick to update the disabled, hidden `select` whenever the `div#styled-select` is updated.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't noticed that his code was disabling the original select. I set the D3 event handler to:

d3.selectAll("ul.select-options > li")
  .on("click", updateAnimal);

and updated the variables in the function:
  var selector = d3.select("div.select-styled");
  var selectedValue = selector.text();

... and it works!